# How to create new vector by using conditionals on another vector?

Tags: r, loops

I have a vector, `my_class`, that is made up of grades. I am trying to generate a new vector, `top_grades`, that is filled up with grades from `my_class` that are greater than or equal to 85. 
I wrote the following code, but the `top_grades` vector ended up being the size of `my_class` vector, with all the grades that were under 85 being returned as NA. I think this happens because some indices of `top_grades` were given no value as the vector was being built.

```
my_class = c(84, 85, 90) #sample vector
top_grades = c() #create vector
for (i in 1:length(my_class)) { #iterate for each index in the length of my_class
  if (my_class[i] >= 85) {
    top_grades[i] <- my_class[i] #the value of top_grades at index i is the value of my_class at index i
  } else {
    next #go to next index if the value of the grade at that index is lower than 85
  }
}
```

I solved this problem by finding a handy function online that removes the NA's from a vector.

```
   top_grades = na.omit(top_grades) #remove NA's from filled vector
```

**My question:** Is there a more elegant way to write this loop that builds the `top_grades` vector without NA's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> top_grades<-my_class[my_class>=85]
> top_grades
[1] 85 90
```

Explanation: If you're using a FOR loop to loop through a vector, you're missing out on the power of R. In this example, you basically want to subset my_class based on the cases that are larger or equal to 85, and place that result into top_grades. my_class>=85 creates a vector (of `length(my_class)`) with TRUE or FALSE for that condition. This vector is then passed as a subset call on my_class, and this returns only those parts of the vector for which the subset says TRUE.

(a two line way of doing the same would be:

```
high<-my_class>=85
top_grades<-my_class[high]
```

which is perfectly equivalent to my one line version)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using

```
top_grades <- my_class[my_class >= 85]
```

Note that `my_class >= 85` creates a vector of boolean variables, and only the `my_class` values where the boolean variable is true are kept.

If you are interested in the indices that make up `top_grades`, you can run

```
which(my_class >= 85)
```

Comment: Wow. I feel like such a noob. Thank you for the clear answer!